# STM32F7-Is there a way to synchronize the output of two different timers in output compare mode?

Tags: timer, clock, stm32f7, clock-synchronization

My processor is an STM32F746ZGT6 and I wish to use TCD132DG, so I need to generate two synchronous clock pulses with different frequencies (One of them is 2 MHz and the other one is 500 KHz) so I used two different timers in output compare mode. The problem is that these two pulses have phase shift. In the Datasheet of TCD132DG the maximum allowed time shift is 60ns while the pulses have 240ns time shift.

Thanks, Amir Reza

Comment: I know nothing about the things you mention, but couldn't you derive the 500 KHz pulse from the 2MHz one, set up a small circuitry to output a pulse for every 4th input pulse? (either way, ignore me, I have no idea)

Comment: Can you not use two output compares from the same timer?

Comment: @Colin one timer can generate one frequency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up the timers in a master-slave configuration so that enabling one timer starts the other. For example,

- Configure `TIM1` master mode to send its Enable as trigger output (`MMS=001` in the
  `TIM3->CR2` register).
- Configure `TIM2` to get the input trigger from `TIM1` (`TS=000` in the `TIM2->SMCR` register).
- Configure `TIM2` in trigger mode (`SMS=110` in the `TIM2->SMCR` register).
- Now setting the `CEN` bit of `TIM1->CR1` should start both timers at once.